# Why and when should I use Sliders instead of regular number Inputs?

Tags: user-experience

Setting the correct value with a slider is a lot more troublesome than with a regular number input with max and min values. Why are they so widespread? When is a slider a better choice in terms of UX?

Comment: When the effect that the value has is what the user is trying to achieve, opposed to the specific value itself. Works best when live updates are shown during sliding. Examples: Volume, brightness.

Answer (score 1):

The slider can be better when:

- User need faster input with predefined values
- User can use the only mouse or touchpad
- Form need already validated values
- Expected users are relatively young